# Deploying my react app on github

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages

I have a master branch and gh-pages.

I was able to see it on gh-pages when a friend developer of mine walked me through it.

I tried to merge the gh-pages with master to add the styling I did and it messed up the viewable app page of github.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "build": "node build.js", 
    "deploy": "npm run build && git-directory-deploy --directory _build/"
  },
  "homepage": "https://marianapt.github.io/reduxTable/",
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,json,css,md}": ["prettier --write", "git add"]
  }
```

thats my package.json

I do npm install  to make sure its all updated..

ever since i merged the master and the gh-pages I cant see my application and im back to seeing the readme page. https://marianapt.github.io/reduxTable/ thats the link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand realy whats happened with you but I think the problem is you lose your prod app.js of master branch when you do the merge.
Just try to run `npm run build` and push again to the github
Hope this will helps you.

Comment: This worked. I tired adding a background and the build didnt like the wrong method. I deleted it, ran it and now its working.!!!